# A way to beat the "Select card" minigame

Tags: hand-of-fate

In Hand of Fate, sometimes you have to choose a card where you have success, fail, huge fail or huge success.

I couldn't find a good way to "beat" that minigame. I always end up selecting fail or huge fail. It is very frustrating!!!

Is there a way to "follow the card"? Or to always select the success card?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To start, we must first understand how the four cards are shuffled (The cards themselves can be any combination of "success", "huge success", "failure" and "huge failure"):

1. The cards start shown face up.
2. The cards are flipped face down, maintaining their positions.
3. The face down cards are shoved into a single pile.
4. From the single pile, the cards are seperated.
5. (Steps 3&4 may or may not be repeated more than once)
6. Figure out the positions of the success cards, and choose one.

The important part to remember while watching steps three and four is that the cards maintain their 'order' in the stack. If we take a theoretical Spread (from left to right) or Huge Success (1), Success (2), Failure (3) Huge Failure (4), it may look like this as it shoves them together:
[image]

(*I've highlighted the cards to better illustrate which ones are top/bottom/middle*)

The top card in this case is Huge Success. When they are pulled apart, you can continue to follow the top card. The easiest two cards to follow, in my experience, are the top and bottom cards. This can get complicated when the cards are shuffled more than once, but it is still possible to follow the cards.

If the there is only a single success card and it ends up in the middle, I tend to eliminate the cards that were on the top and bottom, and then have a 50% chance of getting the correct card, which is better than the base 25% chance of just picking one of the four cards at random.

The difficulty of the chance cards depends how far into the game you are, and the 'difficulty' of the encounter that prompted the chance cards. As the difficulty increases, there may be fewer (huge) Success cards,and more (huge) Failure cards. The dealer will also start shuffling faster, and more than once, making it harder to keep track of the desirable cards.

There are a couple cards you can unlock and randomly obtain in future games that can greatly assist in picking the right cards.

- The blessing [Guardian Angel](http://handoffate.gamepedia.com/Guardian_Angel) will allow you to put back the chance card you picked, shuffle the four cards again and re-choose once per chance encounter. It is no guarantee of getting the right cards, but it does give you another shot at watching the shuffle.
- The equipment [Clairvoyant Helm](http://handoffate.gamepedia.com/Clairvoiyant_Helm), when equipped, will highlight one of the face-down (huge) failure cards in red.

Both of these cards are unlocked by completing [The Apprentice](http://handoffate.gamepedia.com/The_Apprentice) encounter and claiming the card's token by paying either 15 gold or 5 food for a teleportation spell.

Comment: Btw, at the last level of the game, it's impossible to follow the cards, even in easy mode. It shuffle 3 times extremely fast!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes you get lucky though - and the same card will end up at the front three times. In the fast multiple shuffles sometimes it's your only hope if you can't track them.

Comment: How do you track the bottom-most card? In your screenshot, either card 4 or card 2 could be on the bottom at the end of the shuffle. (It looks like card 2 could end up anywhere except the top, really.)

Comment: @PaulMarshall , don't worry about following cards! At tier (level?) 3, the dealer shuffles the cards so fast and so many times that is impossible to follow!

Comment: @vianna77, shuffling speed & type changes on a per-test basis. If you use an early-game card when you're playing against The Dealer (last level in the campaign), you still get a slow shuffle. So even in the last levels, being able to follow a shuffle is important. (It's just not possible on every draw.)

Comment: This is good to know. I thought it was totally random and was just picking the first one every time.

Answer (score -1):

There is another way. Soon as you take the undesired card you close the game using alt+f4. The game hasn't saved your result yet. In the long run you always win, but it requires a lot of patience.

Comment: That would be essentially cheating in the form of savescumming an iron man game. The question asks for methods to play the minigame, not exploit the save mechanic.